# Toggle between Half-adder and Half-subtractor

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra, adder

I have constructed a half-adder that looks like this:

[image]

And a half-subtractor like this:

[image]

It's basically the same circuit except the AND gate at the bottom has a `NOT` before it for one of the inputs. I would like to combine the two so that I can perform (half-) addition or subtraction based upon a third boolean input. Zero would mean Add and One would mean Subtraction. What would be an example of how I could 'route' the input into an optional NOT gate based upon the type of operation being performed?

One idea I had was to put the operation input into an XOR gate before the AND input.

Comment: @jsotola I already did, and it worked. I'm seeing what other solutions there might be.

Comment: @jsotola agreed, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. You could also use a tristate-inverter. However, the XOR gate idea would work better because XOR gates are more common to have. On a side note, I used to think of XOR gates as controllable inverters.